# processing according to the letters in the selected data in the c# combobox

Tags: c#, database, combobox

my question is in a windows form application I made with c#, I am pulling data from the database to the combobox and writing this data to the textboxes. Instead, to act according to the data I selected in the combobox. To give an example, I chose a patient name from the patient table and the patient's name I chose has one of the letters ABC in it, and the data of 45 years old people should come to the textbox1 and textbox2 fields. There is one of the letters DEF in the patient's name and how can I create a structure such that the 75-year-olds' information is textbox1,2 and textbox 3?

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.Text == "") foreach (Control item in Controls) if (item is ComboBox) item.Text = "";
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select *from 
patient where  patient_name like'" + comboBox1.Text + "'", connection);
            OleDbDataReader data = komut.ExecuteReader();
      
            while (data.Read())

            {
                textBox2.Text = data[1].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = data[21].ToString();
                textBox4.Text = data[19].ToString();
                textBox5.Text = data[15].ToString();


            }
```

Comment: I am unable to understand your question. One thing I can say is that it is almost always a mistake to write to text boxes within a loop because they will just always end up with the value from the last row of data.

Comment: To summarize, I would like to write the data I pulled from the database into the textboxes within certain rules. Let's say I have two conditions, if these two conditions are met, the lower values ​​of the selected value should come to the textbox1 and textbox2 fields, but I have another condition, if that condition is met, this time I want to create a structure such that the textbox3 and textbox4 fields are filled.